# Validate email field on keyup event in jquery validate Engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I want to validate email textfield on keyup event in jquery validate Engine. (Only Email Textfield). How it can be done in jquery validate Engine ?

Here is the html:

```
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="validate[required,custom[email]]"  />
```

And here is the JS:

```
    (function($){
        $.fn.validationEngineLanguage = function(){
        };
        $.validationEngineLanguage = {
            newLang: function(){
                $.validationEngineLanguage.allRules = {
                    "required": { // Add your regex rules here, you can take telephone as an example
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Dieses Feld ist erforderlich",
                        "alertTextCheckboxMultiple": "* Please select an option",
                        "alertTextCheckboxe": "* This checkbox is required",
                        "alertTextDateRange": "* Both date range fields are required"
                    },
                    "Marke": {
                        "regex": /^\s*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/ || "none",
                        "alertText": "* Bitte Marke angeben"
                    },
                    "requiredInFunction": { 
                        "func": function(field, rules, i, options){
                            return (field.val() == "test") ? true : false;
                        },
                        "alertText": "* Field must equal test"
                    },
                    "dateRange": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Invalid ",
                        "alertText2": "Date Range"
                    },
                    "dateTimeRange": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Invalid ",
                        "alertText2": "Date Time Range"
                    },
                    "minSize": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Minimum ",
                        "alertText2": " characters allowed"
                    },
                    "maxSize": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Maximum ",
                        "alertText2": " characters allowed"
                    },
                    "groupRequired": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* You must fill one of the following fields"
                    },
                    "min": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Minimum value is "
                    },
                    "max": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Maximum value is "
                    },
                    "past": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Date prior to "
                    },
                    "future": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Date past "
                    },  
                    "maxCheckbox": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Maximum ",
                        "alertText2": " options allowed"
                    },
                    "minCheckbox": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Please select ",
                        "alertText2": " options"
                    },
                    "equals": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Fields do not match"
                    },
                    "creditCard": {
                        "regex": "none",
                        "alertText": "* Invalid credit card number"
                    },
                    "phone": {
                        // credit: jquery.h5validate.js / orefalo
                        "regex": /^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[\ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9\ \.\-\/]{3,20})((x|ext|extension)[\ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid phone number"
                    },
                    "email": {
                        // HTML5 compatible email regex ( http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/states-of-the-type-attribute.html#    e-mail-state-%28type=email%29 )
                        "regex": /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid email address"
                    },
                    "integer": {
                        "regex": /^[\-\+]?\d+$/,
                        "alertText": "* Not a valid integer"
                    },
                    "number": {
                        // Number, including positive, negative, and floating decimal. credit: orefalo
                        "regex": /^[\-\+]?((([0-9]{1,3})([,][0-9]{3})*)|([0-9]+))?([\.]([0-9]+))?$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid floating decimal number"
                    },
                    "date": {                    
                        //  Check if date is valid by leap year
                "func": function (field) {
                        var pattern = new RegExp(/^(\d{4})[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-\.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/);
                        var match = pattern.exec(field.val());
                        if (match == null)
                           return false;

                        var year = match[1];
                        var month = match[2]*1;
                        var day = match[3]*1;                   
                        var date = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // because months starts from 0.

                        return (date.getFullYear() == year && date.getMonth() == (month - 1) && date.getDate() == day);
                    },                      
                 "alertText": "* Invalid date, must be in YYYY-MM-DD format"
                    },
                    "ipv4": {
                        "regex": /^((([01]?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))[.]){3}(([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5]))$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid IP address"
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "regex": /^(https?|ftp):\/\/(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(\#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid URL"
                    },
                    "onlyNumberSp": {
                        "regex": /^[0-9\ ]+$/,
                        "alertText": "* Numbers only"
                    },
                    "onlyLetterSp": {
                        "regex": /^[a-zA-Z\ \']+$/,
                        "alertText": "* Letters only"
                    },
                    "onlyLetterNumber": {
                        "regex": /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/,
                        "alertText": "* No special characters allowed"
                    },
                    // --- CUSTOM RULES -- Those are specific to the demos, they can be removed or changed to your likings
                    "ajaxUserCall": {
                        "url": "ajaxValidateFieldUser",
                        // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                        "extraData": "name=eric",
                        "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
                        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                    },
                    "ajaxUserCallPhp": {
                        "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldUser.php",
                        // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                        "extraData": "name=eric",
                        // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                        "alertTextOk": "* This username is available",
                        "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
                        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                    },
                    "ajaxNameCall": {
                        // remote json service location
                        "url": "ajaxValidateFieldName",
                        // error
                        "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                        // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                        "alertTextOk": "* This name is available",
                        // speaks by itself
                        "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                    },
                     "ajaxNameCallPhp": {
                            // remote json service location
                            "url": "phpajax/ajaxValidateFieldName.php",
                            // error
                            "alertText": "* This name is already taken",
                            // speaks by itself
                            "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                        },
                    "validate2fields": {
                        "alertText": "* Please input HELLO"
                    },
                    //tls warning:homegrown not fielded 
                    "dateFormat":{
                        "regex": /^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$|^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-)31)|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:29|30)))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^(0?2(\/|-)29)(\/|-)(?:(?:0[48]00|[13579][26]00|[2468][048]00)|(?:\d\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid Date"
                    },
                    //tls warning:homegrown not fielded 
                    "dateTimeFormat": {
                        "regex": /^\d{4}[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s+(1[012]|0?[1-9]){1}:(0?[1-5]|[0-6][0-9]){1}:(0?[0-6]|[0-6][0-9]){1}\s+(am|pm|AM|PM){1}$|^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-)31)|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-)(?:29|30)))(\/|-)(?:[1-9]\d\d\d|\d[1-9]\d\d|\d\d[1-9]\d|\d\d\d[1-9])$|^((1[012]|0?[1-9]){1}\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01]){1}\/\d{2,4}\s+(1[012]|0?[1-9]){1}:(0?[1-5]|[0-6][0-9]){1}:(0?[0-6]|[0-6][0-9]){1}\s+(am|pm|AM|PM){1})$/,
                        "alertText": "* Invalid Date or Date Format",
                        "alertText2": "Expected Format: ",
                        "alertText3": "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM|PM or ", 
                        "alertText4": "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM|PM"
                    }
                };

            }
        };

        $.validationEngineLanguage.newLang();

    })
(jQuery);
```

There are other fields too like country Drop down etc, but I want to bind email textfield on keyup event. others should behave in default method

Comment: did you attempt to figure this out on your own?  You need to put forth the least amount of effort.  I would expect you to have tried... say, the "keyup" event.

Comment: I have search about this keyup event but it couldnt helpd me

Answer (score 0):

Reading through the [jQuery Validation Engine documentation](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/), you can validate a field by doing the following:

```
$("#emailInput").validationEngine('validate');
```

In order to check it every time a new character is added, you would do something like this:

```
$("#emailInput").on('keyup', function() {
    $(this).validationEngine('validate');
});
```

Comment: validationEngine has a weird bug when you type fast it validates to false even if the input .val() is a correct one and validates correctly if you don't type fast